# Is the Laplace operator in Sobolev space $W^{2,1}$ sectorial?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Delta$ be the Laplace operator, that is $\Delta f = f''$. It is well known (see, e.g. [this lecture notes](http://www.math.unipr.it/~lunardi/LectureNotes/I-Sem2005.pdf), Chapter 2) that $\Delta\colon D(\Delta) \to L^1(0,1)$ with domain $D(\Delta) = W^{2,1}(0,1)$ is sectorial operator in $L^1(0,1)$.

My question is, if $\Delta\colon D(\Delta) \to W^{2,1}(0,1)$ with domain $D(\Delta) = \{ f \in W^{2,1}\colon \Delta f \in W^{2,1}(0,1)\}$ is still sectorial operator in $W^{2,1}(0,1)$? Is it known theory?

Comment: (a) You probably want to specify boundary conditions (b) The domain is actually simply $W^{4,1}(0,1)$ (with appropriate boundary conditions). You can basically copy the proof in the lecture notes with minor modifications.

Comment: @WillieWong: Thank you very much for your comment. Yes, I forgot about boundary conditions. I thought that I can adopt the proof from the lecture notes, but I don't know how to estimate the $W^{2,1}$ norm (more precisely, I couldn't estimate the $L^1$ norm of the first and second derivative of the solution $u$ of $\lambda u - u'' = f$). How is it possible?